# Is there a CRC32 or other hash function in DB2 for zOS?

Tags: hash, db2, crc32, zos

I'm looking for a DB2 function to calculate hashes on large CLOB values in order to quickly track changes.  Other engines have functions such as `CHECKSUM`,`CRC32` or `MD5`. The function in LUW is `GET_HASH_VALUE` but is not available in zOS.

Constraints: No access to UDFs or Stored Procedures.

Here is a quick and dirty code fragment that computes a CRC32, it only works to about 100 characters.

```
WITH crc(t,c,j) AS (
  SELECT 'Hello World!',4294967295,0 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTR(t,2),bitxor(c,ASCII(t)),8 FROM crc WHERE t>'' AND j=0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t,BITXOR(c/2,BITAND(3988292384,-BITAND(c,1))),j-1 FROM crc WHERE j>0
)
SELECT RIGHT(HEX(BITNOT(c)),8) FROM CRC WHERE t='' AND j=0
```

Result checked against http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html :

```
1
--------
1C291CA3
```

Source: http://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/crc.c.txt

Comment: It's a shame that those constraints are placed upon you. A Metal C or assembler UDF would work wonders here, with low overhead. A basic CRC32 program is available on the CBT Tape (z/OS freeware) web site, look at file #493. DB2 z/OS' goal is to make z/OS and LUW compatible, so open an enhancement request.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on which version of DB2 you have. If you are on DB2 9.7 or higher, have a look here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0055167.html